# Div não respeita limite de imagem no css

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando colocar novas `divs` no meu `html` porem elas acabam saindo da área da imagem e eu não estou conseguindo deixar elas fixas dentro da imagem apenas percorrendo a barra de rolagem, como eu faço para mover os itens e a imagem ficar na posição? Nessa caso é o meu `backgound`... segue exemplo de como esta e exemplo de como eu gostaria

[image: Esta assim]

[image: gostaria assim]

**Meu css da imagem de fundo**

```
.fundoLogin{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url("../../Core/assets/img/fundoLogin.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;;
    background-attachment: fixed!important;
}
```

Comment: Não está muito claro. A imagem de fundo não está ficando fixa?

Comment: Pelo que entendi o problema está no fato da imagem ser muito pequena, coloque seu código html e css relevante

Comment: tente aumentar o .fundologin [ height:100%]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gabriel pelo que entendi da pergunta vc quer que o background ocupe a tela toda e que ele fique fixo mesmo quando de o scroll na p[agina correto?

Bom, para isso é preciso definir uma altura para o `body`, no caso de `100%`, depois vc precisa setar a propriedade `background-attachment:fixed` no background, para ele permanecer fixo enquanto vc rola a página.

Veja um exemplo simples para vc entender como funciona a propriedade:

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/400/300');
            background-size: cover; 
            background-position: center center;
            margin: 0;
            color: aliceblue;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
        <li>item 8</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
        <li>item 8</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
        <li>item 8</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
        <li>item 8</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se essa é a melhor abordagem, mas funciona. Além disso, se lembre que o seguinte código só trabalha com uma única resolução. Portanto, a imagem pode ficar pixelada.

```css
.fundo-login {  
  background-attachment: fixed; /* Faz com que a imagem fique fixa */
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/354/300');
  background-size: cover; /* Faz com que a imagem se estenda proporcionalmente */
  background-position: center center; /* A propriedade anterior pode recortar a image. Por isso, usaremos o background-position para centralizar o corte e tentar capturar o foco da imagem. */
}
```

```html
<body class="fundo-login">
  <div>
    Alguma besteira aqui dentro.
  </div>
</body>
```

Se quiser resolver o problema mencionado (imagem pixelada), alternativamente, pode usar essa outra abordagem. Assim, você vai poder servir uma imagem com resolução diferente para cada viewport.

```css
.fundo-login {
  background-attachment: fixed; /* fixa imagem */
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/354/300');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media (min-width: 530px) { /* Baixa imagem igual a anterior, mas com resolução de  530x420*/
  .fundo-login {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/530/420');
  }
}

@media (min-width: 720px) { /* Baixa imagem igual a anterior, mas com resolução de 720x530*/
  .fundo-login {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/720/530');
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1024px) { /* Baixa imagem igual a anterior, mas com resolução de 1024x780*/
  .fundo-login {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1024/780');
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="fundo-login">
  <div>
    Alguma besteira aqui dentro.
  </div>
</body>
```

Perceba: para usar o método anterior, você deverá renderizar as diferentes resoluções em algum programa apropriado e, então, colocá-las no servidor. Assim, em outras palavras, o browser **não vai converter** automaticamente, mas baixar de acordo com as resoluções.

*Nota: as resoluções utilizadas não são padrões. Por isso, sinta-se livre para escolher as suas.*